# Netbeans bug - False saved file

Tags: github, netbeans

On this image you will have two pictures of the same file. The first one is from netbeans and the second one is from notepad++. After using multiplay different text editors I realized that netbeans didn't update my file properly. Despite telling me it's saved.

This bug also effects git synchronization, it will push the old version to github and not the one that I just updated.

Anyone that knowns how to fix the bug? And how to prevent this in the future?

[image]

For the record this is my netbeans version and pc version:

> **Product Version:** NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201705191307)
>   **Updates:** NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2
>   **Java:** 1.8.0_144; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.144-b01
>   **Runtime:** Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_144-b01
>   **System:** Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; nl_BE (nb)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. If I open a *.java file in NetBeans, then update that same file from Notepad or Notepad++ or UltraEdit that change is automatically shown in the the file in NetBeans 8.2 the moment I save the file in the external editor, with no need for me to do anything.

Comment: Hm, sorry I probally didn't make my post clear enouge. I just used notepad++ as an example how the code is in the saved java file. My issue is a bug that was similar on an older version of netbeans (7.0.1): 
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=206513

The differents this time is that I actually saved, commit, fetched, merged and pushed the file to GitHub and all these changes where never summited. Despite it tells me that the data is commit and merged in the branch I'm working in while in the game files the data is not updated.

Comment: I currently recoverd the data by saving it manually and add them manually again to the project. Hoping the changes will not commit properly. I'm not worried on how this bug was even possible and still apears despite it suppose to be long fixed in this version.

Comment: OK, got it now. I misunderstood the issue. My apologies.

Comment: The data seems to be saved correctly now when I re-add it manually (took me a few hours tho...). I tested some stuff after that and the bug doesn't seem to happen again for now. This experience would possiblility let me reconsider using a different IDE for future projects tho...